# Lion and OpenGL support

Tags: macos, software

Reading this documentation
http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/ i get that Lion support only openGL2.1

This is a 6 years old version, the current one is the 4.2,
Please tell me that i'm not in right and that we are at least at the version 3.2 :) this would be a really really really big problem for me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more modern video cards (and software renderer) OSX does use 3.2 See [Apple's doc on current video cards](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1070_Core.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck unless you're lucky enough to have one [of the few cards](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1070_Core.html) mentioned in Mark's answer. Most new Macs, including all iMacs, support only 2.1 according to [the apple.com page you referenced](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/index.html). This [blog post](http://www.openclblog.com/2011/08/apple-and-opencl.html) by a graphics programming expert also notes that Apple has taken no steps to support OpenCL 1.1 (for programming shaders).

Comment: Are you sure? i have a new iMac with AMD Radeon HD 6770M  and in that page i found that this card support OpenGL 3.2 (i was looking in "legacy" but if you move in "Core" you'll find the right information).

Comment: No, I'm not sure, sorry!